# Como instanciar o $pdo = connect() sem ficar repetindo?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Por exemplo tenho uma classe chamada *user*:

```
class User
{
    public $nome;
    private $email;
    protected $senha;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function insert($email, $senha){
        require_once "conexao.php";
        $pdo = conectar();

        $insertSQL = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl (valores) VALUES (?)');
        $insertSQL->bindValue(1, $this->lalala(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertSQL->execute();
    }
```

e veja também que eu preciso fazer o require():

```
require_once "conexao.php";
$pdo = connect();
```

Mas eu tenho que fazer essas duas linhas toda vez para todo método da classe. Não tem como criar uma única vez e ficar disponível em todo escopo da classe, tipo os atributos?

Já tentei como um atributo e não funcionou. Com o construtor também não foi (talvez eu tenha feito errado).

Comment: Crie uma propriedade de conexão na classe, ela recebe a conexão pelo construtor, sempre que o objeto precisar dela já estará criada.

Comment: Tipo um public $pdo @rray? E no construtor o require e então $pdo = connect()?

Comment: Como assim, me ajuda @rray

Comment: Seu nome é quase igual ao meu @LINQ

Comment: Eu achei bem diferente, @System.Linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma sugestão é criar uma propriedade e conexão na sua classe e passar a conexão para ela via construtor. Assim sempre que o objeto (de `User`) precisar de uma conexão ela já vai estar aberta.

```
class User
{
    public $nome;
    private $email;
    protected $senha;
    private $db; //propriedade da conexão

    //pega a conexão externa e joga dentro da propriedade
    public function __construct($db){
       $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function insert($email, $senha){
       $insertSQL = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl (valores) VALUES (?)');
       //demais códigos ...
}
```

Na hora de chamar faça

```
include 'conexao.php'; 
$user = new User($pdo);

//ou ainda:
$user = new User(conectar());
```

Não tem muita vantagem criar uma função somente para criar e retornar a conexão do PDO com os parâmetros de usuário e senha direto no código, nesse caso pode passar a variável de conexão direto.

Comment: Agora foi e entendi obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```
require_once "conexao.php";

class User
{
    public $nome;
    private $email;
    protected $senha;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function insert($email, $senha){
        $pdo = conectar();

        $insertSQL = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl (valores) VALUES (?)');
        $insertSQL->bindValue(1, $this->lalala(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertSQL->execute();
    }
```

Comment: MAs ai eu vou ter que ficar chamando $pdo toda vez nos métodos não vou?